# How can I keep references to changing spreadsheet constant?

Tags: arrays, google-sheets, reference, google-sheets-formula

I have 2 columns in a sheet that are referencing another dynamic sheet which has new rows added at the top all the time.

I want column `A` to be a copy of column `A` in `Sheet1`, so this works to put in cell `A1`:

```
={Sheet1!A:A}
```

However, I want column `B` to a formula applied to every row in column `B` of `Sheet1`. Problem is, when I put in a a formula, e.g.

```
=formula(B1)
```

then it changes to

```
=formula(B30)
```

when 29 new rows added

I want it to stay as B1, but it won't. If I use an absolute reference $B$1 then I can't copy the formula down the column.

Any wizards out there to help me out?

Comment: Are you asking for the Formula of Cell B1 of Sheet2 to be locked as `=formula(Sheet1!B1)`, even if you insert new rows at the top?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to get the matching row from a column of another worksheet, then use `INDEX` and `ROW`, like so:

```
=FORMULA(INDEX(Sheet1!$B:$B, ROW(), 1))
```

This will always return the value in Column B of Sheet1, on the same Row as the formula is in on Sheet2 - even if you insert rows at the top of Sheet1

Answer (score 0):

You can do "partially absolute reference" (I don't know the correct way of saying this).

You can lock only the column so would be `=$A1` which means that it will never change the column but when you drag down the formula, it will change to `=$A2`, `=$A3`...

Or you can lock only the row typing `=A$1` This way it will be locked on the row only.

You can do this also by pressing F4 several times: 1 time will lock both, the 2nd time will lock the row only, the 3rd time the column only and the 4th time will delete the locking.

Comment: The way I read it, the OP wants the reference to remain on B1 even if a new line on that sheet is added.  Even with absolute references it will move to B2 if a new line is added at row 1.

Comment: Well, if that is the case (adding columns on top) the only way to leave this fixed would be by using the `INDIRECT` function: `=INDIRECT("B"&1)` this way Excel will not change the row number.

However, be careful with using this function as uses a lot of resources. Do not abuse of this in the spreadsheet :)

@halfiranian can you clarify our doubt here?

Comment: No, the INDEX function shown by Chronocidal will do it and it is not volatile and will iterate as the user drags it down.

Answer (score 0):

the proper way would be to use `INDIRECT` like:

```
=INDIRECT("Sheet1!B1:B")
```